# Algorand: What is the purpose of VRF

Tags: cryptography

In the paper describing Algorand,two reasons are given to use verifiable random functions/cryptographic Sortion:

> Sortition provides two important properties: First, given a random seed, the VRF outputs a pseudo random hash value, which is essentially uniformly distributed between $0$ and $2^{hashlen}-1$. [..] Second, an adversary that does not know $sk_i$ cannot guess how many times user $i$ is chosen, or if $i$ was chosen at all.

Why is the the second property important? What would be the attack scenario if adversaries could predict when user $i$ is chosen?

Comment: I don't think this subject is off topic because VRF are considered for staking purposes in eth 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

If validators are known in advance they can be attacked with a denial of service preventing them for fulfilling its role. Delaying the block production or choosing another validator favorable to attackers.